# Is there a way to use index while writing a csv file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm stuck here with a small Problem. I have a python tcp Server running on my pc reciving data from a Client.  I Need to automaticly write a csv file. now the only Problem is data is being overwritten in the first row, is there a way to give an index to the data I'm reciving? help would be great. Thanks!

```
#while connected
while 1:
    data = con.recv(Buffer_size)
    writer  = csv.writer(open(filename+".csv", 'w')
    writer.writerow('\n'data)
```

Comment: Change  writer  = csv.writer(open(filename+".csv", 'w') to  writer  = csv.writer(open(filename+".csv", 'a')

Answer (score 1):

You send the argument `'w'` to `open()`. `'w'` means

> w: open for writing, truncating the file first

(https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Change this to `'a'`

> a: open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists

and you will append to the end of the file.

I.e.

```
#while connected
while 1:
    data = con.recv(Buffer_size)
    writer  = csv.writer(open(filename+".csv", 'a')
    writer.writerow('\n'data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm still very new to python